# Unable to run javac though java is working

Tags: lubuntu, java

I am getting the error message below when I run `javac` on ubuntu terminal:

```
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-4.6-jdk
 * gcj-4.7-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
 * openjdk-6-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

While `Java -version` is working.

How to resolve this?

Comment: It tells you exactly what to do. Try `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` or whatever version of the JDK you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having jre installed, since `java -version` is working. You will be able to execute java class programs with java. However, to compile java programs, you will need jdk, as [Nattgew](https://askubuntu.com/users/15341/nattgew) suggested. You can install openjdk from the software center or from the terminal using:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

or if you need Oracle's jdk, see this question:

- [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary java jdk 6/7/8 or JRE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre)

Comment: @Vickal: Consider accepting the answer(clicking on the check mark besides the answer) if it has helped you.